# Metamap run local raise "Error when querying Prolog Server: Connection refused"

Tags: java, nlp

I follow [this](http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/Docs/README_javaapi.shtml) steps to run the Metamap Java API 2014 on Linux platform
([Main page from metamap](http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/))

After start Metamap server, I run some main class in Metamap JavaAPI pakages, but it raises `Error when querying Prolog Server: Connection refused`

Then I check if the Metamap server is running on port `8066` by using the command: 
 `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8066`

but I receive nothing.

Did anyone had the same problem before and knows solution for this?

Comment: Did you run `./bin/mmserver{two-digit-year}`?

Comment: In the Metamap 2014 it changed mmserver{two-digit-year} to metamap14
I already run skrmedpostctl and  wsdserverctl and then run metamap14.

Comment: I doubt that. I have installed Metamap 2014, and in order to run the Java API, the `mmserver14` executable needs to be run.

Comment: Thank so much Chthonic! I found mmserver14 in JavaAPI folder, my mistake looked into Metamap folder. Now I can start an run success!

Comment: You are welcome :-) ... metamap installation can be quite confusing at times (I speak from personal experience). Added my comments as an answer. If this solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `skrmedpostctl` (and the optional word sense diambiguation server `wsdserverctl`), you need to run the `mmserver` executable in order to use the Java API for Metamap. This can be run by running the command

```
./bin/mmserver{two-digit-year}
```

Also, be sure to include the two jar files for metamap and prolog-beans in your classpath (in your IDE, this can be done by adding a dependency to these jars).

Comment: Hi @Chthonic Project,@Latent Boy. I recently have started using the metamap14 api in windows. Initially from the **mmserver directory[14 GB]** I first start  `skrmedpostctl_start.bat` . Post that I run `metamap14.bat`. However in my java code, I still encounter 
`Error when querying Prolog Server: Connection refused: connect`.
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may reside with the timeout: when the timeout parameter is not specified for the MetaMapImpl, it is set to 0, so the instance interprets any latency as failure and reports an error.

Increase the timeout to a reasonable value (for me 500 msec was enough).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after getting error SPIO_E_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES and losing the connection to the mmserver. I was tryig to construct instances of `MetaMapApiImpl` in a loop and calling `processCitationsFromString` for thousands of times. Therefore, I was getting error SPIO_E_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES after around a hundred repeats.

What I did to fix this error was to simply disconnect the api at the end of the loop, by calling the function `disconnect()`.